# Offset of a variable (inherited from the base template class) shadowed by a member with the same name

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, tuples, offset

I have a tuple class implemented using inheritance (it's from *C++ Templates: The Complete Guide, 2nd Edition*, Vandevoorde, Josuttis, Gregor):

```
template<typename... _Value>
class Tuple {};

template<unsigned int HEIGHT, typename _Value>
class TupleElement {
public:
    TupleElement() = default;

    template<typename _OtherValue>
    TupleElement(_OtherValue && other): _value{std::forward<_OtherValue>(other)} {}

    _Value _value;
};

template<typename _Head, typename... _Tail>
class Tuple<_Head, _Tail...>: public TupleElement<sizeof...(_Tail), _Head>, public Tuple<_Tail...> {
    using HeadElement = TupleElement<sizeof...(_Tail), _Head>;
public:
    template<typename _HeadArgument, typename... _TailArgument>
    Tuple(_HeadArgument && head, _TailArgument &&... tail): HeadElement{std::forward<_HeadArgument>(head)}, Tuple<_Tail...>{std::forward<_TailArgument>(tail)...} {}

    _Head & getHead() {
        return static_cast<HeadElement *>(this)->get();
    }

    const _Head & getHead() const {
        return static_cast<const HeadElement *>(this)->get();
    }

    Tuple<_Tail...> & getTail() { return *this; }

    const Tuple<_Tail...> & getTail() const { return *this; }
};

template<>
class Tuple<> {};
```

I'm using this template to create new types as if they were structures with homogeneous member variables ordered by the template arguments' order. I need the offset of every inherited `_value` member. I'm trying to achieve it with `offsetof`, but passing `_value` with the type of the tuple returns:

```
using T = Tuple<int, float>;
offsetof(T, _value);
```

#### The error

```
1>***.cpp(22): error C2385: ambiguous access of '_value'
1>***.cpp(22): note: could be the '_value' in base 'TupleElement<1,int>'
1>***.cpp(22): note: or could be the '_value' in base 'TupleElement<0,float>'
```

Comment: There is no such error, since none class is instantiated. Please post [mcve]

Comment: Just putting this out here: there's `std::tuple`

Comment: @PasserBy The implementation of std::tuple doesn't preserve the order of the template arguments.

Comment: *The implementation of std::tuple doesn't preserve the order of the template arguments.* What? Could you be more specific?

Comment: and the implementation of `getHeight<>()` is...

Comment: @PasserBy If I created a tuple `std::tuple<int, float>`, the int value wouldn't precede the float value in the memory.

Comment: @max66 Sorry, I forgot to remove this friend function declaration.

Comment: Yeah, I just tested it out, I'm surprised. [Ignore the UB](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/262fcd4ad6c5cee7)

Comment: Your implementation wouldn't guarantee anything about the layout either, plus it's full of unndefined behaviour (every single identifier that starts with _ and a capital letter gives you UB).

Answer (score 0):

You have two _value's in your class, and that's what the error is saying.
You can get the offset of both of them like this:

```
int off1 = ((size_t)&reinterpret_cast<char const volatile&>((((T*)0)->::TupleElement<0, float>::_value)));
int off2 = ((size_t)&reinterpret_cast<char const volatile&>((((T*)0)->::TupleElement<1, int>::_value)));
```

Comment: Binding a null reference is strictly UB.

Comment: This is how offsetof works in VS2017 anyway :). You can change it to a pointer if you prefer.

Comment: @Alex - The standard library can use code that is formally UB, if the specific compiler cares to define the behavior. The original reason for `offsetof` being part of the C standard library is that you just cannot write it in proper, portable code.